# Multi-Touch not detected on any gameobject

Tags: touch, multi-touch, unity-game-engine

I have made a script and attached it to main camera and the multi-touches are not being detected on any where on game scene. The console logs update at each frame but the input touches is not logged anywhere.None of the print statement runs inside the if statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void Update() {
        print("update");
        if (Input.touchCount > 0){
            print("touch detected");
            print(Input.touchCount);
            print(Input.touchCount.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have to get single touch then use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`. This will work on all platforms. Editor or device.

You can use it as,

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Screen touch detected");
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Screen touch and drag detected");
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Screen touch lifted up");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only for a mouse click, not touch.

Comment: Strange, people with lesser knowledge have that much confidence. For your kind information mr. @joreldraw it works as touch too.

Comment: Not for multitouch... lesser knowledge.

Comment: Read answer carefully, I wrote for single touch, and don't cover up, you said it will work only for click not touch and now you are saying multitouch... contradictions

Comment: You need to read the question: Multi-Touch not detected on any gameobject

Comment: It is the edited one by kagkar, and what so ever, you said only for click, that is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There is not only a "touch" word in touchable devices. There are several types of touch action such as single touch, multi-touch, swipe, pinch etc.

At first please delete the print function in update, it's unnecessary and silly action.

For a single touch, (as [Hamza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318711/hamza-hasan) said) you can use `Input.GetMouseButton` or `Input.GetTouch`.

If you want to calculate the count of multi-touch, your usage is true. Try to attach script to another game object in scene. See [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) example for more on Unity's official page.